# First mouse drag movement

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to figure out the first drag movement of the mouse in Java?

For example:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (first drag of the mouse)  // what should I write here?
        System.out.println("This is the first drag");
    else System.out.println("This isn't the first drag");
}
```

If I drag the mouse 5 times I should see this text in the console:

```
This is the first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
```

Comment: Good old boolean flags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean first=true;//this should be a instance variable.
```

first drag! use a boolean variable to detect first or not.like this

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (first) { // this is only true if it's first drag
        System.out.println("This is the first drag");
        first=false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This isn't the first drag");
    }

}
```

update...

this is how u can detect is it first drag.but there are a problem normally mouse drag event triggered while dragging.to avoid this u can modify this little bit.

declare instance variables

```
boolean draging = true;
boolean mark = true;
boolean first = true;
```

print only when dragging start.when we print mouse dragging we stop printing it until mouse released and redragging.

```
public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        draging = true;
        if (mark) {
            if (first) {
                System.out.println("This is the first drag");
            }else{
                System.out.println("This isn't the first drag");
            }
            mark = false;
        }
}
```

change first to false so first dragging is enough.and ready for print new drag[mark = true]

```
public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
          if (draging) {
            mark = true;
            first=false;
        }
}
```

this is the output of 1st and updated examples.there is a problem of 1st code [because event drag is triggered continuously while dragging ,not ones].

first example

```
This is the first drag
This is the first drag
This is the first drag
.............................//this continues until u finish[released] first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
................................
```

updated one

```
This is the first drag //a drag [ click--move--relesed] mark only 1time
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
This isn't the first drag
...............................
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify FastSnails solution to this slightly to get around the behaviour that mouseDragged fires on *every* mouse movement while the button is down:

```
boolean first = true;
boolean triggered = false;

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    if(!triggered){
        if(first){
            System.out.println("This is the first drag");
            first=false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("This isn't the first drag");
        }
        triggered = true;
    }
}
```

Of course, we then have to reset that flag in a mouseReleased event, which signals the end of the "drag":

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    triggered = false;
}
```

Using this method means that the message only gets triggered once per "drag", rather than at every mouse movement.